# how to make url case insensitive for spring boot restful service

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am building a spring boot application version 3.1.4 & spring boot starter web version 3.2.X. For my application, I want to make the url case insensitive.

I looked at multiple solution nothing seems to be working.

**Solution one**: in `application.properties` set `spring.mvc.pathmatch.matching-strategy=ant_path_matcher`

**Solution two**:

```
import org.springframework.util.AntPathMatcher;

public class CaseInsensitivePathMatcher extends AntPathMatcher {

    public CaseInsensitivePathMatcher() {
        setCaseSensitive(false);
    }
}


import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.CorsRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.PathMatchConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

@Configuration
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configurePathMatch(PathMatchConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.setPathMatcher(new CaseInsensitivePathMatcher());
    }

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
                .allowedOrigins("*")
                .allowedMethods("*")
                .allowedHeaders("*");
    }
}
```

**Solution three** : use `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` which is **now** **deprecated**.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages="org.saat")
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configurePathMatch(PathMatchConfigurer configurer) {
        AntPathMatcher matcher = new AntPathMatcher();
        matcher.setCaseSensitive(false);
        configurer.setPathMatcher(matcher);
    }

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new 
InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return viewResolver;
    }

}
```

Please help

Comment: just an idea: maybe you can use a webfilter to make the path (and maybe query parameters) all lower- (or upper-)case and then configure your services just with that casing?

Comment: Did you have a look at this is it not working ??https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/17876#issuecomment-453428363

Comment: @JayYadav: `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter ` is been deprecated and is no longer supported.

Answer (score 0):

**This is what worked for me :**

```
@configuration
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer{

   @override
   public void configurePathMatch(PathMatchConfigurer configurer){
        AntPatchMatcher  matcher = new AntPatchMatcher ();
        matcher.setCaseSensitive(false);
        configurer.setPathMatcher(matcher);
   }


}
```